# Image exceeds flex parent size

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am having an issue with making `<img>` flexible inside a flex parent. Image start exceeding parent dimensions. I would like to leave parent with `display: flex;` and  restrict image from crossing parent's dimensions.

```css
.full
{
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
.half
{
  width: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 20px;
}
img
{
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="full">
  <div class="half">
          <h1>title</h1>
          <img src="http://placehold.it/90x200">
  </div>
</div>
```

Can you please explain and give some useful links that would explain the shown behavior and possible solution of it?

I am using both Firefox and Chrome to view that. Issue persist in both browsers.

---

It seems that question is duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41674979/flex-child-is-growing-out-of-parent)

Comment: TLDR of the duplicate, change the alignment of the flex container to `flex-start`, the issue is the stretch

Comment: @TemaniAfif adding `justify-content` doesn't seem to fix the issue (as the snippet shows)

Comment: @TemaniAfif More than parent does not expand to accommodate child as described in the possible duplicate question/answer.

Comment: yes the duplicate deal with more things no present here, but I didn't find another one like yours ... and it's not justify-content but `align-items` ... probably Michael_B or someone else will find a better duplicate

Comment: @hrust, you are the first person which I have ever seen, who has marked his own question as a duplicate! Incredible! My respect to you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for it to work `.half` div also needs to be a flexbox container and the image needs to have `min-height: 0`, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41674979/flex-child-is-growing-out-of-parent).

```css
.full
{
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
.half
{
  width: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
img
{
  min-height: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="full">
  <div class="half">
    <h1>title</h1>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/90x200">
  </div>
</div>
```