# Column flex child won't shrink and wrap

Tags: css, flexbox

In this horizontal card layout demo the text content won't shrink and wrap. You can see some of text overflows the card.

```css
h1, h2, p {
  font-family: Lato;
}

.section-heading {
  margin: 2rem 0 0.5rem
}

.user-card {
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 1rem;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 12px 0px;
  max-width: 500px;
}

.user-card__heading {
  margin: 1rem 0 0;
  font-size: 2.5rem
}

.user-card__bio {
  margin: 0.25rem 0;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.user-card__list {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.user-card__list-item:not(:last-of-type)::after {
  content: "|";
  color: gray;
}

.user-card__list-item p {
  margin: 0;
  color: gray;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.user-card__image {
  border-radius: 50%;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

/* FLEX */
.user-card--flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-height: 200px;
}

.user-card--flex .user-card__list {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  width: 100%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.user-card--flex .user-card__list-item {
  display: flex;
}

.user-card--flex .user-card__list-item:not(:last-of-type) {
  margin-right: 0.25rem;
}

.user-card--flex .user-card__list-item:not(:last-of-type) p {
  margin-right: 0.25rem;
}
```

```html
<article class="user-card user-card--flex">
 <img class="user-card__image" src="https://www.fillmurray.com/200/200" />
 <h1 class="user-card__heading">Bill Murray</h1>
 <p class="user-card__bio">Actor, comedian, filmmaker, and writer.</p>
 <ul class="user-card__list">
  <li class="user-card__list-item">
   <p>Los Angeles, California</p>
  </li>
  <li class="user-card__list-item">
   <p>Member since August 18, 2018</p>
  </li>
 </ul>
</article>
```

The same code can be found in [this StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/flex-issue).

I have tried the solutions mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12022288/how-to-keep-a-flex-item-from-overflowing-due-to-its-text?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41674979/flex-child-is-growing-out-of-parent). Needless to say they didn't work.

I believe it has something to do with my use of `flex-direction: column` but I'm not sure what exactly.

Comment: consider CSS grid in this case

Comment: @TemaniAfif, I considered that duplicate as an option, but I don't think the question is asking for the container to expand. I think it's asking for the text to wrap inside the fixed-width (500px) container.

Comment: @Michael_B hm, true .. I see both problem related but maybe it's not trivial. Feel free to reopen if you have a different opinion and an answer.