# Why has CSS overflow property on parent effect on size of IMG child?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

The following does exactly what I want, but I don't understand why, which annoys me.

I want:

- the `"second"` `div` to take as much space as it can, within the constraints of its parent
- then divide that space evenly amongst it's 2 child `div`s
- scale the `img`s so that they fit exactly in their parent `div`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .root {
        width: 500px;
        height: 500px;
      }
      .flex-container {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        background-color: red;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
      }
      .first {
        background-color: blue;
      }
      .second {
        background-color: darkmagenta;
        flex-grow: 1;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        overflow: hidden;
      }
      .wrap {
        height: 50%;
        width: 100%;
      }
      img {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="root">
      <div class="flex-container">
        <div class="first">
          This div should be sized accoring to it's content and wrap if needed
          which it does, nice!
        </div>
        <div class="second">
          <div class="wrap">
            <img
              src="https://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/30000/velka/cat-13476279941Ls.jpg"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="wrap">
            <img
              src="https://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/30000/velka/cat-13476279941Ls.jpg"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

After experimenting and messing around I arrived at this HTML and CSS. Crucial is the `overflow: hidden;` on the `"second"` `div`. Without it, the child `img`s are displayed larger, growing the `"second"` `div` beyond its parent.

I do not understand how `overflow: hidden;` can affect the size of the childs -  I would have expected them to be clipped. Any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a nicer way to do this in this post: [flex child is growing out of parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41674979/flex-child-is-growing-out-of-parent)

Instead of putting `overflow: hidden;` on the parent, that posts suggest setting `min-height: 0;` which allows its children to shrink and become smaller than their content.

That makes more sense to me.

EDIT
Found this post with even more detail, and a link to the flexbox spec which explains it all: [Why don't flex items shrink past content size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36247140/why-dont-flex-items-shrink-past-content-size)

> On a flex item whose overflow is visible in the main axis, when specified on the flex item’s main-axis min-size property, specifies an automatic minimum size. It otherwise computes to 0.